# MySQL Query returning strange result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
select c.company_id,c.company_name, pe.pe_relationship, opt.oo_type 
from pub_entity pe 
    inner join company c 
        on c.company_id = pe.pe_company_id 
    inner join opt_out opt 
        on opt.oo_company_id=c.company_id
where pe.pe_pn_id in 
       (SELECT pn_id 
        FROM pub_notice 
        WHERE pn_company_id=2523);
    and opt.oo_type not in 
       ('image','iframe')
```

However, when I run the query, in `opt.oo_type` column I am still getting `image` and `iframe` results.

`opt.oo_type` is of type `enum('image','iframe','other')` Can anyone tell me why I am still getting those results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `;` at the end of your first `WHERE` clause, which is cutting off your `NOT IN` clause.  Move it to the end of the query:

```
select c.company_id,c.company_name, pe.pe_relationship, opt.oo_type 
from pub_entity pe 
inner join company c on c.company_id = pe.pe_company_id 
inner join opt_out opt on opt.oo_company_id=c.company_id
where pe.pe_pn_id in (SELECT pn_id FROM pub_notice WHERE pn_company_id=2523)
and opt.oo_type not in ('image','iframe');
```

Comment: just curious... MySQL allows you to pass this sql to the database, where the semicolon truncates the sql into two parts one of which is completely malformed, and does not complain ?

Comment: My immediate thought was that it should have thrown an error for the second batch, but if it did execute the top query with the batch terminator where it was, it would have produced exactly the results he described.

Comment: yes, that makes sense, perhaps he simply did not include the error in his question... I was wondering, because I have heard that MySQL is unusually forgiving of what, in other SQL products, would be considered malformed or invalid queries.  ... But this looked really egregious.